# invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00 while postgress import from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am importing data from S3 csv file to Pstgress RDS using  aws_s3 Extention
and it gives an error in between import

**Command**

> psql=> SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
> 't1',
>
> '(format csv)',
> :'s3_uri'
> );

**Error**

ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
CONTEXT:  COPY t1, line 7324484

I tried to change the column type to text but not working

Comment: What does line 7324484 look like? The error message indicates that the source data is not valid UTF-8, not that your column type is incorrect. Perhaps it isn't really UTF-8?

Comment: row data looks correct and when i cleaned data with the redshift translate command,
I am able to import data in RDS

Answer (score 1):

If you really have ASCII 0x00 in your input data you need to specify this as the NULL character with NULL AS '\000' in your COPY command.

See - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html

Answer (score 0):

My  data was contain invalid values, and that needs to be cleaned

while I was trying to export data from Redshift and import it to S3,
I found redshift has some support to clean this type of data

here is link to the solution
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/remove-invalid-characters-redshift-data/

thanks